# ASM visitLocalVariable Not Working

Tags: java, local-variables, java-bytecode-asm, visitor-pattern

I am trying to use ASM5.0 MethodVisitor to get some information about the local variables with the visitLocalVariable. However, when I run the code, it seems the visitLocalVariable never runs.

```
public static class ModifierMethodWriter extends MethodVisitor{
    private String methodName;

    public ModifierMethodWriter(int api, MethodVisitor mv, String methodName) {
        super(api, mv);
        this.methodName=methodName;
    }

    // **some other visitor method, which works well, including "visitVarInsn"...**

    public void visitLocalVariable(String name, 
                                   String desc, 
                                   String signature, 
                                   Label start, 
                                   Label end, 
                                   int index) {
        super.visitLocalVariable(name, desc, signature, start, end, index);
        System.out.println("LOCAL - " + name + " TYPE: " + desc + " " + signature + " INDEX: " + index);       
        // nothing get print in this method
    }

}
```

It is an example revised from the demo class ClassModifierDemo.java from the following link http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/manipulating-java-class-files-with-asm.html

Comment: Visiting local variables requires the associated debugging attribute to be present for the code. Otherwise, the JVM has no notion of names and scopes of local variables and even their formal type may change.

Comment: @Holger Got it! But is there a way to distinguish the scope of local variable with ASM? For example, there are 2 loops in a method call(so the variables in the 2 loops belongs to different scope). And I want to know which variable belongs to which loop. Is that possible? Big Thank

Comment: On the byte code level, local variables are just a slot in the stack frame addressed by index. That slot may represent the same source level variable throughout the code or different variables at different code locations. You can only use stores into the slot to deduce whether a new scope started due to the fact that a previous value became inaccessible. If the new value has an incompatible type, it’s clearly a new variable from Java source code perspective (if the byte code was generated by compiling Java source code at all) but if the new value has a compatible type you can’t be sure.